# functional implementation of updating a useState variable not changing the value appropriately

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function that updates the State values of chatId, currUser, and msg. This function is called twice, so I expect the values to be updated twice. However, the values are only updated once. What am I doing wrong?

This the function:

```
const displayMessage = (message) => {
    const newMsg = { id: chatId, text: message, sender: currUser };
    setChatId((prevId) => prevId + 1);
    setCurrUser((prevUser) => {
      return prevUser === "user" ? "bot" : "user";
    });
    console.log(`currUser: ${currUser}`);
    setMsg((prevMsg) => [...prevMsg, newMsg]);
  };
```

This function is being called in fetchApi() and handleSend().

This is the entire code:

```
import {
  Box,
  TextField,
  Button,
  Typography,
  Avatar,
  Grid,
  Paper,
} from "@mui/material";
import SendIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Send";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const messages = [
  { id: 1, text: "Hi there!", sender: "bot" },
  { id: 2, text: "Hello!", sender: "user" },
  { id: 3, text: "How can I assit you today?", sender: "bot" },
];

function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [msg, setMsg] = useState(messages);
  const [chatId, setChatId] = useState(4);
  const [currUser, setCurrUser] = useState("user");

  const fetchApi = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.omdbapi.com/?apikey=213f50cd&t=${input}`
      );
      displayMessage(response.data.Plot);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleSend = () => {
    if (input.trim() !== "") {
      console.log(`user input: ${input}`);
      // setCurrUser(currUser === "user" ? "bot" : "user");
      // setCurrUser((prevUser) => (prevUser === "user" ? "bot" : "user"));
      displayMessage(input);
      fetchApi();
    }
  };

  const displayMessage = (message) => {
    const newMsg = { id: chatId, text: message, sender: currUser };
    setChatId((prevId) => prevId + 1);
    setCurrUser((prevUser) => {
      return prevUser === "user" ? "bot" : "user";
    });
    console.log(`currUser: ${currUser}`);
    setMsg((prevMsg) => [...prevMsg, newMsg]);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setInput(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        height: "93vh",
        display: "flex",
        boxSizing: "border-box",
        flexDirection: "column",
        bgcolor: "grey.200",
        margin: "25px 100px",
      }}
    >
      <Box sx={{ flexGrow: 1, overflow: "auto", p: 2 }}>
        {msg.map((message, index) => (
          <Message key={index} message={message} />
        ))}
      </Box>
      <Box sx={{ p: 2, backgroundColor: "background.default" }}>
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          <Grid item xs={10}>
            <TextField
              size="small"
              fullWidth
              placeholder="Type a message"
              variant="outlined"
              value={input}
              onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={2}>
            <Button
              fullWidth
              color="primary"
              variant="contained"
              endIcon={<SendIcon />}
              onClick={handleSend}
            >
              Send
            </Button>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}

const Message = ({ message }) => {
  const isBot = message.sender === "bot";

  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: isBot ? "flex-start" : "flex-end",
        mb: 2,
      }}
    >
      <Box
        sx={{
          display: "flex",
          flexDirection: isBot ? "row" : "row-reverse",
          alignItems: "center",
        }}
      >
        <Avatar sx={{ bgcolor: isBot ? "primary.main" : "secondary.main" }}>
          {isBot ? "B" : "U"}
        </Avatar>
        <Paper
          variant="outlined"
          sx={{
            p: 2,
            ml: isBot ? 1 : 0,
            mr: isBot ? 0 : 1,
            backgroundColor: isBot ? "primary.light" : "secondary.light",
            borderRadius: isBot ? "20px 20px 20px 5px" : "20px 20px 5px 20px",
          }}
        >
          <Typography variant="body1">{message.text}</Typography>
        </Paper>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default App;
```

I tried updating the state variables using the functional way but it still didn't work.

Comment: You have leaked your (private?) API key. Invalidate the key and generate a new one.